# Are there examples of nontrivial $f$ for which the antiderivative of $\tan\circ f$ is known?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm looking for an example of a function $f$ (apart from inverse trigonometric and linear functions) such that $\int\tan(f(x))dx$ is known. Special functions included in the typical CAS are acceptable for both $f$ and the antiderivative.

Comment: Well, $\arcsin$ is not very interesting, but technically not mentioned.

Comment: $\int \tan(x^{1/n})$ can be expressed in terms of polylogarithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int \tan(\ln x)\; dx = -ix+x{\it LerchPhi} \left( -{x}^{2\,i},1,-i/2 \right)$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP does not want He wants them defined in elementery functions.

Comment: "Special functions included in the typical CAS are acceptable"